# swagger (from Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli) Could not load file or assembly 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger in WSL2

Tags: .net, ubuntu, swagger, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Installed for cli in ubuntu 22.04.2 under WSL2 to generate openApi spec

```
dotnet tool install Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli -g
```

I can see that it is installed using

```
dotnet tool list -g
```

However when I try and generate any file, I get a file not found exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger, Version=6.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=62657d7474907593'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger, Version=6.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=62657d7474907593'
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_4(IDictionary`2 namedArgs)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 68
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 59
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 121
```

Prior to this I also had the issue of swaager command not found, after installing, but adding

```
# set PATH for dotnet
if [ -d "$HOME/.dotnet/tools" ] ; then
    PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools"
fi
```

to ~/.profile fixed the pathing problem